# How to Handle Scriptable Object Items that have to change Data at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory-management, scriptable-object

I have an Item class that stores ItemSO  scriptable object

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ItemSO inventoryItem;
}
```

My Item SO is an abstract class that stores general info that every item has

```
public abstract class ItemSO : ScriptableObject
    {
        public string ItemName;
        public GameObject prefab;
    }
```

For every specific Item type, I made another Scriptable object that inherits from ItemSO

```
public class FuelItemSO : ItemSO, IDestroyableItem
{
    [Tooltip("Burn Time of the fuel in minutes")]
    public float BurnTimeIncreasePerKg;
    public float TemperatureIncreasePerKg;    
}
```

Now everything was working fine, while I was using my Scriptable objects as data containers as they are meant to be, but now I need to have another Item type, where I need to change the values of the variables. Let's say this class

```
public class ContainerItemSO : ItemSO, IDestroyableItem
{
    public float maxAmount;
    public float CurrentAmount;    
}
```

I can't seem to find a solution how the base Item class would GET, and SET different data according to the ItemSO. Like let's say it's a water container, and I want to add water into it.

I'm thinking of having an interface IHaveChangableData that ContainerItemSO will inherit from

```
public interface IHaveChangableData 
{
    ContainerData GetData();
}
```

and maybe a ContainerData class that will store the variables, so that I don't store them directly in the Item class

```
public class ContainerData
{
    //No idea how to store ItemSO specific data
}
```

idk if I'm overcomplicating stuff, but maybe someone could share a solution to this.

Also, should I consider so switching to classes from Scriptable objects if I want to have a coulpe of items with changeble data?

Answer (score 2):

it's not very straightforward to revert runtime changes to scriptable objects, as they're designed around the idea of being configurations rather than runtime data. However if you're looking for a way to do this anyway, my suggestion is not to serialize your runtime data, so for example your `ContainerItemSO` class would look like so:

```cs
public class ContainerItemSO : ItemSO, IDestroyableItem
{
    public float maxAmount;
    [NotSerialized]
    public float CurrentAmount;    
}
```

or make it a property, whatever works best for you.

If you want the runtime data be inspectable and serializable (maybe for testing scenarios?) you can create a separate type for runtime data and make a copy on OnEnable

```cs
public class ContainerItemSO : ItemSO, IDestroyableItem
{  
    public float maxAmount;
    public RuntimeData runtimeData { get; set; }
 
    [SerializeField] 
    private RuntimeData serializedRuntimeData;
     
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        runtimeData = serializedRuntimeData;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct RuntimeData
    {
        public float CurrentAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. As I understood for an inventory system where Items have variables that are going to be changed Scriptable Objects are not the way to go. So what's the way to go in this situation? Should I have the base classes themselves as a list in my Inventory?

Comment: What's wrong with the property approach?

Comment: @VavAvagyan this is a very opinionated matter and would be outside the context of this question. In my opinion (and I encourage you to explore other options besides this) is making components for runtime data, and SOs for persistent data. you'll use cross-scene references this way. to solve that, if needed to, I make SO adapters that take in reference to the component that contains our data. the component then adds itself to the SO on Awake or Start. 

+ If you decide that my answer (not this one, the main answer post) was the right one for your post's question, please mark it as answer.

Comment: @derHugo nothing wrong at all. it can be up to the design choice of the code. a property or field without `NotSerialized` attribute will remain after a domain reload as Unity serializes them to persist (point 3 onwards at https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html#:~:text=What%20Unity%20performs%20when%20Scene%20Reloading%20and%20Domain%20Reloading%20are%20both%20enabled ). so if we use property without the attribute, the property will stay edited after domain reload

Comment: @Coolguy I know, question was more towards OP ;) It seems to pretty much solve the use case in my eyes .. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77538732/7111561) were my alternatives but the properties is probably even more straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on your exact requirements.

The property approach as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77536270/7111561) is actually pretty clever and intuitive.

---

You could also e.g. simply use a **copy** instance at runtime:

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ItemSO _inventoryItem;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _inventoryItem = Instantiate(_inventoryItem);
    }
}
```

This creates a clone of the referenced ScriptableObject while entering playmode / when being spawned. So the original SO would never be touched and modified at all.

Drawback: If you need those all to be connected to the original SO then this would not work as every instance would end up with their own respective clone instance ;)

---

You could however introduce a global Singleton Manager to handle that and only create one clone per instance of any SO

```
public static class SOManager
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<ScriptableObject, ScriptableObject> cloneByOriginal = new();

    public static T GetCloneSave(T original) where T : ScriptableObject
    {
        if(!cloneByOriginal.TryGetValue(original, out var clone)
        {
            clone = Instantiate(original);
            cloneByOrigonal[original] = clone;
        }

        return clone as T;
    }
}
```

and then use

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ItemSO _inventoryItem;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _inventoryItem = SOManager.GetCloneSave(_inventoryItem);
    }
}
```

This way there should only be created a clone **once** and every other user of the same SO - which has to also use the upper way for getting the clone - would get the same SO instance so they are all connected again but to a runtime clone instance of the original SO without ever touching the original one.

---

*Typing only on the phone but I hope the idea gets clear*